# Finding out if keypress changed the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible with only one bind to either `keyup`, `keypress` or `keydown` to find out that the field value has been changed?

I mean - some key presses don't change the value (like pressing left arrow) and some do (like pressing any letter-button or backspace).

So is it possible to know that key press caused the value change having only one binding?

PS: yes, I realize I could save the value somewhere and compare it in the very begin of event handler, but is there a solution without temporary variables?

Comment: Do you want to account for the following situation as well: You press the left arrow, and an event binded to the keypress makes it's own modifications to the textbox.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: not actually. I want something to happen only if keypress caused the real value change.

Comment: you should also consider the fact that you can change the value of an input field *without actually pressing a key*. You can select text and move it around via drag&drop. You can remove selected text via context menu. You can copy&paste via context menu. etc..

Comment: @Kaii: exactly. And I only need to care of changes made by keyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think so. I mean, you can map key codes that you assume will be silent, but that map might not be 100% reliable as the input value can change or loose focus depending on how the OS and browser is set up.

Is there a special reason for not detecting change via a variable? It seems like the most reliable thing since this is also exactly what you need to detect:

```
var input = $('input'),
    val = input.val();
input.keyup(function(e) {
    ​​​​​​​if (val != (val = $(this).val())) {
        console.log('change');
    }
});​
```

If you don’t want to use stray variables, how about saving it in the `data` attribute?

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
    ​​​​​​​if ($(this).val() != $(this).data('value')) {
        console.log('change');
    }
    $(this).data('value', $(this).val());
});​
```

**Update based on your comment**

You can also use the `input` event (in modern browsers) to detect change if you don’t care about keys:

```
$('input').bind('input', function() { 
   console.log('changed');
});
```

The last option would be to use an interval and keep checking the input field (this might be the most reliable option).

Comment: I don't want to find out that using variable because not only key pressing could change the field value. And if user used mouse to insert/cut the text from the field - the value would become obsolete. Also browser itself (autofill feature) could change the value. So I don't want bothering to all these edge cases (as long as this becomes error prone)

Comment: I see, so you are not really after the key codes? See my edit.

Comment: I'm only care of key codes. What I wanted to say is that intermediate variable can become to not actual state by using mouse. So the solution with manual variable introduces the requirement of handling much more events rather than just keypresses

Comment: So let me get this straight – You want to detect silent keycodes, even if the user inputs via other methods (f.ex mouse, copy/paste etc)?

Comment: nope, sorry for being so un-understandable :-( What I want to detect - is **only keypresses** that change the value. The intermediate value wouldn't work in 100% cases because let's suppose you have "123" in input and saved "123" in a variable. You then select "2" by mouse and "Cut" it. After that you put the cursor between "1" and "3" and press "2". So literally the value has been changed, but the code is not able to catch that.

Comment: Well, I decided that I could live with 99.99% accuracy and small fails that occur in only very specific cases, thanks ;-)

Comment: You can combine a `keyup` with an additional `input` event (or use an interval) that keeps the data in sync if the user manipulates via another interface than the keyboard, that would probably increase the stability a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

Based on information from MDN's [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/KeyboardEvent) section, it looks like that:

- all keys you are interested in will [reliably generate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/KeyboardEvent#Auto-repeat_handling) a `keypress` event each time the key is about to be processed
- you can tell which key is being pressed (`keyCode` / `key`), and also if it has a printable representation [or not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/KeyboardEvent#Virtual_key_codes) (if it does then it will alter the value; but keys without printable representation may also alter it)

Going to other sources than MDN yields also [this nice resource](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) which has information on how the `keyCode` property is populated across browsers.

A superior alternative to the above would be the DOM level 3 [`textInput`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-textinput) event, which however also has serious drawbacks:

1. It is not currently implemented across major browsers
2. It does not, as far as I can see, apply when text is *removed* from an input element

Comment: So your proposal is to have the list of keycodes that I'm interested in?

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure you cannot do this **properly** without storing the original value somewhere.

Try this if you only want to detect the changes really done by keyboard interaction.

```
$('#foo').keydown(function (e) {
    this.data = this.value;
});

$('#foo').keyup(function (e) {
    if(this.data != this.value) {
        console.log('changed from "' + this.data + '" to "' + this.value + '"');
    }
});
```

Note there still is the cornercase when the user holds a key down (lets say: arrow key), then modifies the field content with the mouse, then releases the key.

But this is very unlikely to happen and i guess is acceptable.

Comment: Yep. And the same can be done in a single keyup event. Just move `this.data = this.value;` to the last line of `keyup` handler.

Comment: @zerkms No. On first invocation, `$('foo').data` is undefined. When there is a pre-inserted `value="bar"` in the input field, it would indicate change on first invocation if user presses an arrow key. Try it out. http://jsfiddle.net/5h8DD/

Comment: tiny `typeof this.data != 'undefined'` fix could solve that. And in that case we would still have one event handler, not two: http://jsfiddle.net/GmB9j/

Comment: @zerkms yay got some sleep. actually, `typeof this.data != 'undefined'` doesn't fix the problem, it just reverses the case. Now, on first invocation a change would be ignored if the user presses a key (lets say: letter) that changes the value. ;-)